# How do we prove such integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\infty\frac 1{1+x^n}dx=\frac\pi n\csc\left(\frac\pi n\right)$$

If we want to prove the left side equal to the right side in this case, how do we start? How do we prove this definite integral?

Comment: Do you know about complex contour integration? This is the approach that I would use for this problem (for $n>2$; for $n=1$ and $n=2$ the problem is pretty easy.)

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: Do a search there are at least 3 question that have this solution.

Comment: okay. can you solve this one for me as an intro to that?

Comment: Without contour integration this problem is not easy. If I were told "do this without using contour integration" I would have to partial fraction expand $\frac{1}{1+x^n}$, which still requires complex numbers (albeit not the residue theorem).

Comment: Literally all you needed to do was a search: [pick your poison](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bx%5En%7Ddx%24)

Comment: For posting on this site, you need to learn math markup! ($\LaTeX$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $t=\dfrac1{1+x^n}$ , then recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral,

and employ Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) in order to obtain the desired result.